# How to get N last items from a nested array of dictionaries sorting by a value in the dictionaries with pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a nested array of dictionaries in my mongo collection.

I update arrays with new dictionaries according to the period of the array, ie 5min, 15 min, 30m etc, and append the dictionaries to the array.

I need to query the array sorting by "timestamp" and getting the most recent N entries.

I have tried this query which results in 10 items from the array. But the result is not sorted. I use find_one() as there is only one document with the respective symbol

```
timeframe = "5min"
symbol = "EURUSD"
data.find_one(
            {"$and": [
                {"symbol": symbol},
                {timeframe: {"$exists": True}},
                {timeframe+".rates": {"$exists": True}}
            ]
            },
            {timeframe+".rates": {"$slice": 10}},           
            sort=[
                ("5min.rates.timestamp", pymongo.DESCENDING)
            ]
            )
```

This is the structure of a document:

```
{ _id
  symbol
  5min: {
         "last_refreshed": sometime,
         "rates": [ {
                     "timestamp":
                     "open":
                     "low":
                     "high":
                     "close":
                     },
                  ]
         }
  15min: {}
  ...
}
```

Comment: You will need to use an aggregation pipeline with the $match, $unwind and $sort operators.

Comment: I tried with $group with no result. How shall I use $match in this case?

Comment: $match filters out the records you want, $unwind converts the array to individual documents and $sort sorts the output.

Comment: Thanks, I got the right pipeline with $match.

Answer (score 1):

I used an aggregation which solved the problem

```
symbol = "EURUSD"
timeframe = "5min"

pipeline = [
        {"$unwind": "$"+timeframe+".rates"},
        {"$match": {"symbol": symbol}},
        {"$sort": SON([(timeframe+".rates."+"timestamp", 1)])},
        {"$limit": 5}
    ]

pprint.pprint(list(raw_data.aggregate(pipeline)))
```